# Tab transition icon like Tinder

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I'm looking for a way of doing the same transition effect than when swipping among tabs in Tinder application.
- Color transition.
- Image transition.

Like on the picture below:

[image]

If anyone already have an idea on how to do that, I'm in.
If not, I will share my results here on how to accomplish that.

Comment: did you got same transition like tinder icon ?

Comment: No, I still didn't find it, for now, no time to real search deeper on how to make it by my own...

Comment: i was also looking for the same i think changing icon in on tab change listener may work.

Comment: https://github.com/MathiasSeguy-Android2EE/AnimatedVectorMorphingTool

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

[Tinder-Like-Action-Bar](https://github.com/AtomicSpider/Tinder-Like-Action-Bar)

Comment: Thx for this link, but not actually. The transition between tab switch is not as smooth as the one in Tinder. But it can be a start for achieving what I want to.

Answer (score 0):

This question might be old but here's how you would proceed with the animation:

```
ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);

    adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(vpPager);

    TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener tabListener = new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout) {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

           // You are interested in the positionOffset parameter
           // You would need its value in order to make a Property Animator
           // on your custom Tab drawable
            Log.d("onPageScrolled", "Changing position: " + position + ", offset: " + positionOffset);
        }

    };

    vpPager.addOnPageChangeListener(tabListener);
```